# How to return string with recursion in python?

Tags: python, recursion

Hello how do I return a string(not just printing it) using recursion?

```
def listOddLen(l):
#@param l:list
  list=""
  if len(l)>0:
    if len(l[0])%3==0:
      list=list+l[0]
      print list
      return listOddLen(l[1:])
   else:
     return listOddLen(l[1:])
```

Comment: Anything wrong with that code? Any specific question?

Comment: If you provide us with the details of 1. what you want your code to do (i.e. the specific return value you expect) and 2. what your code actually returns, it is much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something in a function, you can always use `return` + variable. For example, in this case, you could change `print list` to `return list`.

Comment: thank you but if I use "return list+listOddLen[1:] "it outputs this error:The error value is: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
Inappropriate argument type.
An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.

Comment: Did you try using `str()`. For example: `return str(list+listOddLen[1:])` or `return list + str(listOddLen[1:])`

Comment: Yes! thank you  return list+str(listOddLen(l[1:])) works the only issue is it will add a "None" at the end of the new string

Comment: To remove the `None`, you can either get rid of the `+ str(listOddLen[1:])` or use `.replace("None", "")`

Comment: Thank you for the help bro!